# Using a user defined parameter in file name

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access Database that outputs a report in Excel format.

The report is dependent on a date parameter chosen by the user. This parameter is selected via a textbox (text100) that has a pop up calendar.

I would like to use the date in the text box (text100) in the filename.

Comment: You are not providing enough information to get this question answered. Mainly: How are you currently creating the export files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take responsibility for asking for the parameter. I like using global parameters that I can get/set via global functions - this way they can be set anywhere and the queries can have access to them as well.

**Just need a couple subs/functions in module:**

```
Some Module

Dim vParam1 as variant
Dim vParam1 as variant

Public Sub ParameterSet(byval pParamName as String, byval pParamValue as variant)

Select Case pParamName 
  Case "Param1": vParam1 = pParamValue 
  Case "Param2": vParam2 = pParamValue 
  Case Else
    msgbox pParamName & " parameter not defined"
End Select

End Sub

Public Function ParameterGet(byval pParamName as String) as variant

Select Case pParamName 
  Case "Param1": ParamGet = vParam1 
  Case "Param2": ParamGet = vParam2 
  Case Else
    msgbox pParamName & " parameter not defined"
End Select

End Sub
```

**Then in your query** (remove the date parameter)

```
WHERE Field1 = ParameterGet("Param1")
```

**Then in your code where you run the export**

```
Private Sub Export_Click()

  dim vParam1 as variant

  vParam1 = inputbox("Enter the parameter:")

  ParameterSet "param1", vParam1

  Transferspreadsheet blah, blah, FileName:= vParam1 & ".xls"

End Sub
```

Obviously this code needs a little tweaking to compile...  :-)

Comment: It is usually recommended that forms are used for parameters in Access. You have a great deal more control over the input.

Comment: Of course - but this is a quick and dirty solution for one parameter - I usually use forms for parameters - the idea is still the same - you save the entered value into the global var and close the form.

Answer (score 1):

It's apparent to me that you want to parse a date out of a filename, and then use this date to perform a query... if that's not what you want, please re-formulate the question.

I assume the last part is pretty obvious : concatenate the string converted date with the rest of your query string, and submit it to execution.

The part less obvious is the parsing.
You need to define a filename format. Is it:

- "OUTDATA-YYYYMMDD"
- "OUTDATA _YY _MM _DD"
- "DD _MM _YYY _OUTDATA"
- or something else?

We need to know the tokens relative position (Year, Month, Day and ordinary file name).

Assuming "YYYY_ MM_ DD_ OUTDATA.DAT", here's a thought...

```
function toQueryDate(aFileName as String) as Date
Dim theQueryDate as Date
Dim theParsedDate as String

theParsedDate=Mid(aFileName,1,4)+"/"+Mid(aFileName,6,2)+"/"+Mid(aFileName,9,2)
'IMPROVE:there's no error checking here.... we could see if the individual tokens are numbers

On Error Resume Next
theQueryDate=Cdate(theParsedDate)
If err.number then
   Msgbox "Bad filename: "+aFilename
   End 'or something else less fatal 
Endif

'we should be OK so:
toQueryDate=theParsedDate
End function
```